# How to parameterize nested JSON object in Arm template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

below is the Arm Json that I am using to deploy the Consumption plan on Azure. Works perfectly. I want to how can we parameterize nested object in Arm:

```
       {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
              "name": "Y1",
              "tier": "Dynamic",
              "size": "Y1",
              "family": "Y",
              "capacity": 0
            },
            "properties": {
              "computeMode": "Dynamic"
            }
        }
```

For Example, If I want to parameterize **sku** property? It contains name, tier, size, family and capacity. I know how to parameterize each one separately for example:

```
"name": "[parameter('sku_name')]",
"tier": "[parameter('sku_tier')]"
```

But is it possible to parameterize the complete **sku** property in one go? Like:

"sku": "[parameter('sku')]"

But how it will be assigned in parameters section then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the shared information I understand that you are trying to create consumption based function app using nested arm template.

> But is it possible to parameterize the complete sku property in one go? Like: >"sku": "[parameter('sku')]"

Yes, you can create sku parameter of object type in your nested template and use it in `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms` block in your main template.

To test this I have created a nested template to deploy consumption based plan and declared the sku properites block in parameters as shown below

[image]

Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/azure-resource-manager/advanced-templates/objects-as-parameters) for more information on How to use objects as parameters in your ARM templates.